# How to determine average dwell time within a geometrical area

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, time-series

I have a database with device coordinate time-series (timestamp, x, y, device_id). How can I determine the longest dwell-time over multiple devices within an area and timeframe in SQL?

Here is an example of the data I have (note that is not on regular intervals)

```
|         ts         |  x  |  y  | device_id 
---------------------+-----+-----+-------------
 2015-10-24 14:12:39 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:40 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:51 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:52 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:53 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:56 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:57 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:58 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1
 2015-10-24 14:12:39 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 2
 2015-10-24 14:12:40 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 2
 2015-10-24 14:12:41 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2
 2015-10-24 14:12:42 | 1.5 | 1.0 | 2
 2015-10-24 14:12:45 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 2
 2015-10-24 14:12:48 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 2
 2015-10-24 14:12:49 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 2
```

Here the dwell-times for device 1 within the area (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0) would be 12 seconds (14:12:39 to 14:12:51) and 1 second (14:12:57 to 14:12:58). The dwell-time for device 2 within the same area would be 2 seconds (14:12:39 to 14:12:41). The max would be 12s, the min would be 1s and the average would be 5s.

I had the initial idea of partitioning the data on device_id to get sets for each device and then determining the duration between min(ts) and max(ts) as the longest period for that device and then doing a max on the period across all devices using the following as a sub query.

```
SELECT (max(ts)-min(ts)) as longest_period, device_id
FROM readings
WHERE x < 1.0 AND x > 0.0 AND y < 1.0 AND y > 0.0
GROUP BY device_id, ts
```

Comment: How are you defining an area?  The `x` and `y` are exactly the same?

Comment: These are two devices moving in a larger area and the x and y in the table is their location at any given time. The size of the total area (in my case 10.0x10.0) doesn't matter since I am only looking at a small portion of the area that I define to be from (0.0,0.0) to (1.0,1.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was writing the question I started to expand on my own idea and a few web searches later and reading the Postgres documentation (which is awesome btw ;) I created the following query which seems to perform really well and do what I want. I'll admit it is a little more complex than I had anticipated.

```
select
  hour,
  (extract(epoch FROM max(t2.duration)))::int as max_dwell_time,
  (extract(epoch FROM min(t2.duration)))::int as min_dwell_time,
  (extract(epoch FROM avg(t2.duration)))::int as avg_dwell_time
from
  (
    select
      t1.device_id,
      date_trunc('hour', t1.ts) as hour,
      sum(t1.duration) as duration
    from
      (
        select
          distinct(ts),
          device_id,
          lag(ts) over (order by ts) as prev_ts,
          ts - lag(ts) over (order by ts) as duration
        from
          spatial_readings
        where
          x < 10.0 and y < 10.0
        order by device_id, ts
      ) t1
    where t1.duration < interval '60 second'
    group by t1.device_id, date_trunc('hour', t1.ts)
    order by t1.device_id
  ) as t2
group by hour
order by hour;
```

The inner most query (t1) determines the gap between timestamps using postgres window functions, the middle query sums up all durations that are less than the 60s threshold and groups by hour and device. The outer most query then extracts the max, min and average dwell times in seconds and displays for each hour.

Here is an example result based on my test data

```
hour                 | max_dwell_time | min_dwell_time | avg_dwell_time 
---------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
...
2015-10-24 14:00:00  |             77 |             21 |             49
2015-10-24 15:00:00  |            177 |            109 |            143
2015-10-24 16:00:00  |              4 |              4 |              4
2015-10-24 17:00:00  |             41 |             41 |             41
2015-10-24 18:00:00  |             18 |             18 |             18
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to answer your question, at least for one device and area:

```
SELECT (max(ts)-min(ts)) as longest_period, device_id
FROM readings
WHERE x < 1.0 AND x > 0.0 AND y < 1.0 AND y > 0.0
GROUP BY device_id
ORDER BY longest_period DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You can easily add whatever restriction you want on `ts` as well.

Comment: This query works but it assumes that the device doesn't go outside the area and back in within the time frame being looked at. If the device is present in the area for 1 minute and then leaves for 30 minutes and then comes back for 2 minutes the longest dwell time is 2 minutes but the query above would return 33 minutes as the longest dwell time which in my case is wrong.